# How can I increase the size of the icon alone in FAB.Group in react-native-paper

Tags: css, react-native, stylesheet, react-native-paper

I need to customize the FAB.Group with my custom icon and the text.

If I set the width and height the image gets hiding and simultaneously it increasing the size of the text too. How can I style this image as big and text as it is in react-native-paper.

[image]

Comment: maybe use default button with icon instead?